# Docker with ngnix and angular stuck at start worker process 30

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, nginx-reverse-proxy

Im trying to containerize angular application.
here's my docker file

```
FROM nginx
LABEL author="sreeya"
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/ngnix.cong
```

I used

```
docker build -t nginx-angular -f nginx.dockerfile .
docker run -p 8080:80 -v $(pwd)/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx-angular
```

build was a success, but docker run got stuck at

```
start worker process 30
```

Here's the full output

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2021/12/28 16:14:03 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2021/12/28 16:14:03 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.4
2021/12/28 16:14:03 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
2021/12/28 16:14:03 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 4.19.130-boot2docker
2021/12/28 16:14:03 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2021/12/28 16:14:03 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2021/12/28 16:14:03 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
```

Please help me resolve

Comment: you're missing a `ENTRYPOINT` line in your Dockerfile

Comment: Im following a tutorial and https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular-Core-Concepts and this link has the code. Please notice that the docker file has no ENTRYPOINT and it seems to be working for him

Comment: hey! according to those docs, youre supposed to use docker-compose, not docker

Answer (score 2):

The container is up and running, it didn't stuck there. The container is run in attached mode by default. You can either run the container in detached mode using command -

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v $(pwd)/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx-angular
```

Or leave it open and try checking container status in new terminal using command -

```
sudo docker ps
```

Comment: yeah, but when I visit myip:8080, I see 403 forbidden - nginx. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Add a conf under /etc/nginc/conf.d/ or /etc/ngix/sites-enabled inside docker and add server location block in it.